# How do assignments work in enqueue operation in Java linked list implementation

Tags: java, object, nodes, singly-linked-list

I recently tried to implement a queue with linked list in Java. `enqueue`, The function to add items to the queue is as follows.

```
void enqueue(int key) 
    { 

        // Create a new LL node 
        Node temp = new Node(); 

        // If queue is empty, then new node is front and rear both 
        if (this.rear == null) {
            temp.setData(key); 
            this.front = this.rear = temp; 
            return; 
        } 
        temp.setData(key);
        // Add the new node at the end of queue and change rear 
        this.rear.setLink(temp); 
        this.rear = temp; 
    }

class Node{

    private int data;
    private Node link;

    public int getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getLink(){
        return this.link;
    }

    public void setLink(Node link){
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Node(){
    }
}
```

This is working as expected, but the thing that I cannot understand is the last two lines of this function.first we set the link of current rear to the new node, then immediately `rear` is assigned the new node. What happened to the previous value stored in `rear`?

Comment: If `rear` is just a reference to the last element in the list, it's just being overwritten and the old value discarded. Once you add an element to the end of a queue, you'd need to update any references to the last element, since there's a new last element now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rear** is just a reference which points to the last element inserted into the Queue. Lets say your current queue has the following elements *1 -> 2 -> 3(rear)*. The **rear** is now pointing to 3. Now let's say you call enqueue(4). The current **rear's** link(next) pointer should point to the new node. The line `this.rear.setLink(temp)` is doing exactly that. The current queue's contents will be *1 -> 2 -> 3(rear) -> 4*. We need to update the new **rear**. `this.rear = temp` is doing exactly that. Eventually the queue's contents will be *1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4(rear)*

Comment: That means though we update `rear`, content pointed by `rear` previously are not discarded since it is just a pointer.Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. They are not discarded but it is not because of what you mentioned. Don't forget `front`. As long as `front` is pointing towards the first object the list won't go anywhere. If both `front` and `rear` are set equal to null the list will get collected by Garbage Collector.